# Under what condition(s) running a simple regression between two time series variable is valid?

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Suppose we have two stationary time series variable: gdp growth rate and S&P 500 returns. And, we fit a simple linear regression model for S&P 500 returns with gdp growth rate as the sole explantory variable. No lag terms involved in this specification.

When is this valid/adequate?

If residuals of this regression satisfy standard assumption of stationarity, no autocorrelation and homoscedasticity then can we go ahead with this simple linear regression model.

When would we need more advanced time series model which involves multiple lags of these variables (ARIMA, VAR, VECM etc).